# How do I initialise all entries of a matrix with a specific value?

Tags: arrays, matlab

In [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29), if I wanted to get a 10 element list which only contained the number 5, I could do something like this:

```
take 10 $ repeat 5
```

Output:

```
[5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
```

Is there anything like this in Matlab?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It is easy to assign repeated values to an array:

```
x(1:10) = 5;
```

If you want to generate the array of elements inline in a statement try something like this:

```
ones(1,10) * 5
```

or with [`repmat`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html;jsessionid=f1464648af2c6b017506485689f6)

```
repmat(5, 1, 10)
```

Comment: `x(1:10)` also works for a character, and `repmat(..)` also works for a string. For example: `repmat('ab', 1, 10)` gives `abababababababababab`.

Answer (score 22):

The ones method is much faster than using repmat:

```
>> tic; for i = 1:1e6, x=5*ones(10,1); end; toc
Elapsed time is 3.426347 seconds.
>> tic; for i = 1:1e6, y=repmat(5,10,1); end; toc
Elapsed time is 20.603680 seconds.
```

And, in my opinion, makes for much more readable code.

Answer (score 6):

Given a predefined `m-by-n` matrix size and the target value `val`, in your example:

```
m = 1;
n = 10;
val = 5;
```

there are currently `7` different approaches that come to my mind:

---

**1) Using the [repmat](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) function** *(0.094066 seconds)*

```
A = repmat(val,m,n)
```

**2) Indexing on the undefined matrix with assignment** *(0.091561 seconds)*

```
A(1:m,1:n) = val
```

**3) Indexing on the target value using the [ones](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ones.html) function** *(0.151357 seconds)*

```
A = val(ones(m,n))
```

**4) Default initialization with full assignment** *(0.104292 seconds)*

```
A = zeros(m,n);
A(:) = val
```

**5) Using the [ones](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ones.html) function with multiplication** *(0.069601 seconds)*

```
A = ones(m,n) * val
```

**6) Using the [zeros](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html) function with addition** *(0.057883 seconds)*

```
A = zeros(m,n) + val
```

**7) Using the [repelem](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) function** *(0.168396 seconds)*

```
A = repelem(val,m,n)
```

---

After the description of each approach, between parentheses, its corresponding benchmark performed under `Matlab 2017a` and with `100000` iterations. The winner is the `6th` approach, and this doesn't surprise me.

The explaination is simple: allocation generally produces zero-filled slots of memory... hence no other operations are performed except the addition of `val` to every member of the matrix, and on the top of that, input arguments sanitization is very short.

The same cannot be said for the `5th` approach, which is the second fastest one because, despite the input arguments sanitization process being basically the same, on memory side three operations are being performed instead of two:

- the initial allocation
- the transformation of every element into `1`
- the multiplication by `val`

Answer (score 5):

See [repmat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) in the documentation.

```
B = repmat(5,1,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers you can use:

```
>> tic; x=5*ones(10,1); toc
Elapsed time is 0.000415 seconds.
```

An even faster method is:

```
>> tic;  x=5; x=x(ones(10,1)); toc
Elapsed time is 0.000257 seconds.
```

Comment: By using `timeit` (which is more robust than `tic`/`toc`) and an example with much more than 10 elements, **this can be shown to be false**. The first method is quicker, a test as quick as yours is unlikely to be accurate - for instance simply re-running your example a few times gives different conclusions. Try: `m1 = @() 5*ones(1e7,1); x = 5; m2 = @() x(ones(1e7,1));` To set up anonymous functions which run your tests, then time using `timeit(m1)` and `timeit(m2)`. I get that `m2` is ~3x *slower*. Yes, this is a valid method to create a single-valued array, but it is not a faster method.