# Is there any difference in time complexity and memory complexity of zeros and ones in Matlab

Tags: matlab, memory, time, time-complexity, space-complexity

In Matlab does both the commands use same size of memory and is their time complexity same too?

```
B = zeros(5)
B = ones(5)
```

Comment: You can test it yourself by timing the functions. `zeros` tends to be faster, because the OS can return zero-initialized memory, but not one-initialized memory. This means that MATLAB must fill the `ones` array with values, but not the `zeros` array.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48724131/3978545) addresses timing for many different initialisation methods